# Android: Edit text hint

Tags: android-layout, android-edittext, android

I am developing an application. In that in xml lay out i am taking an Edit Text and setting it background from drawable.

Now what i want is that - I want to set hint to drawable and also want to set text as shown in image.[image]

I tried to set hint but when i am setting hint. It ok. But when i set the 140 character left that time hint hides.

I want to keep that 140 character left at the time also when user is going to type. And on every character the character left is going to reduce.

So how to do that please guide me...

Comment: Use a `TextView` to show the remaining characters and a `TextWatcher` on your `EditText` to update the "chars left" counter.

Comment: The thing you want to do is not **android:hint** . Try the first commentator's suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `TextWatcher` on `EdiText` and Use a `TextView` to show the remaining characters

```
private TextView mTextView;
private EditText mEditText;
private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       //This sets a textview to the current length
       mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
};
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Must Take Your EditText in a Relative layout So you can set a textview whose value will be changed on typing a single letter So you need to implement Textwatcher for that.